# Writing List[Node] to an xml file in scala

Tags: xml, scala, nodes

I am tring to write a list of `Node (xml's node)` to xml file.

By writing:

```
 val xml = <x>{nodes}</x>
```

where nodes are the list of nodes- I am getting all the nodes in one line .

What can I do to print every node in a new line?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096938/generating-formatted-xml-in-scala) In short, you can `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter` for your purposes. You should also remember (you probably do) that these classes are shipped in a separate library as of 2.11 release.

E.g.:

```
scala> val printer = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)

scala> val nodes = List(
           <lol>node level 1</lol>, 
           <bar><foo>node level 2</foo></bar>
       )

scala> printer.formatNodes(nodes)
res1: String =
<lol>node level 1</lol><bar>
  <foo>node level 2</foo>
</bar>
```

Actually, when I look at the result, I see that it differs somewhat from the desired output. I'd recommend using a little bit longer, but more matching to your expectations, variant:

```
nodes.map(node => printer.format(node)).mkString("\n")
```

That will separate each node by `\n`:

```
<lol>node level 1</lol>
<bar>
  <foo>node level 2</foo>
</bar>
```

Comment: the command "res0.format Nodes(nodes)" doesn't work - it asks for more parameters - do you know why?

Comment: What library version do you have? Can you share the exact version of the code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: "scala-xml" % "1.0.2"

Comment: Hmm, that's strage. Maybe try to refresh your project or make sure you've got binary compatible builds of the libraries. Also, note that I updated the answer to match your question more precisely and the new variant doesn't use `formatNodes`. Anyway, you should check your libraries' compatibility.

Comment: in format or in formatNode it asks to send not just the node (or nodes) but a Binder as well...

Comment: @user3725190, I'm sorry, but can you please share minimal working (not working) code sample? I'd like to either get the error stack trace myself or from you. (Here's a nice page on how you can make your questions/comments more useful: http://sscce.org/)